# recyclerview addOnLayoutChangeListener() not recognizing all positions in the list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView `addOnLayoutChangeListener()` to find clicked position and revert focus on last clicked item from the list. But `findViewByPosition(int position)` method only recognize first 7 items, out of 11.
So if the clicked item is at position 8,9,10 or 11 `view` is null and not requesting focus.

```
 if(clickedPosition !=-1){
    recycler.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {
            View view = recycler.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(clickedPosition);
            if (view != null) {
                view.requestFocus();
            }
            clickedPosition = -1;
            recycler.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you just want to do something when an item is clicked, just set an onClickListener to the item. Generally you do that in you ViewHolder. The ViewHolder implements View.onClickListener and you do `view.setOnClickListener(this)` in the ViewHolder's constructor

Comment: The reason it is null is because the way recycler view works.It only adds(renders/makes) views as and when required and hence if you have rendered till say for eg views till view no 7, the views after that are still not generated or added and hence views after view no 7 will be null.

Comment: Thanks udit7395, `recycler.scrollToPosition(clickedPosition)` renders views and returns focus on clicked item.